# How to type cast using Sun/Oracle CodeModel library?

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I'm trying to use the Java [CodeModel library](http://codemodel.java.net/) to generate some code.  In my generated code I need to perform a type cast.  I want something like this...

```
foo.setBar( ((TypeCastToThis)someVariable).getBar() );
```

The only support I've found in the library is by using [JCast JExpr.cast(JType type, JExpression expr)](http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JExpr.html#cast%28com.sun.codemodel.JType,%20com.sun.codemodel.JExpression%29).  However according to Eclipse the return type, JCast, is not public.  The exact error is: "The type com.sun.codemodel.JCast is not visible".

Here's a simple example of what I'm doing.

```
import java.io.File;

import com.sun.codemodel.JBlock;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCast;  //<-- Eclipse flags this as an error
import com.sun.codemodel.JClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JClassAlreadyExistsException;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpr;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMethod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JVar;



public class CastTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JClassAlreadyExistsException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
        JDefinedClass testClass = codeModel._class("MyTestClass");

        JMethod testMeth = testClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, codeModel.VOID, "TypeCastTestMethod");

        JBlock testMethBody = testMeth.body();

        JVar castMeVar = testMethBody.decl(codeModel.INT, "castMe", JExpr.lit(42));

        JClass typeCastToThisClass = codeModel.directClass("TypeCastToThis");

        JCast castResult = JExpr.cast(typeCastToThisClass, castMeVar);

        testMethBody.decl(typeCastToThisClass, "theTypeCastedObject", castResult);

        codeModel.build(new File("/path/to/output/directory"));
    }

    /*

    The generated code should look like this.

    public void TypeCastTestMethod()
    {
        int castMe = 42;
        TypeCastToThis theTypeCastedObject = (TypeCastToThis)castMe;
    }

    */
}
```

Am I using the library incorrectly and/or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue later it can be by-passed by using implicit upcasting to a JExpression from a JCast on the return value of JExpr.cast(....).  JCast is a subtype of JExpression.

From....

```
JCast castResult = JExpr.cast(typeCastToThisClass, castMeVar);
```

To.....

```
JExpression castResult = JExpr.cast(typeCastToThisClass, castMeVar);
```